# Allow popups to show through another layer

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-draw

I have a Leaflet feature layer (Layer1) with popups bound. 
I'm using Leaflet Draw to draw a polygon in Layer2 over the feature layer. 
I want to then be able to open the popups for Layer1 while still having Layer2 visible on top of Layer1.

Here is an example: 
http://jsbin.com/keroyoy/8/edit?html,js,output

The layer of white squares has popups:

[image: I can open popups in the layer behind]

But when I draw a polygon over them, it blocks me from opening popups.

Is there a way to click 'through' the top layer? A way to make it not have a fill? I don't want to stack Layer2 behind with layer.bringToBack() because then it's not visible.

Comment: See my updated answer, I think I've got a working example for you to try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got this up and running here for a [live example](http://jsbin.com/gusijigizi/edit?js,console,output)
As a work around for not showing popups when clicking through a polygon, I opted for listening on mouseclick that would produce a popup at that point. The popup draws over top of the polygon.

Add a variable to track if you're currently editing:

```
var currentlyEditing=false;
```

You need to listen to the draw and end of draw event:

```
//listen to draw event
map.on(L.Draw.Event.DRAWSTART, function (e){
  console.log("drawing");
  currentlyEditing=true;
})
//listen to end
map.on(L.Draw.Event.DRAWSTOP, function(e){
  console.log("end");
  currentlyEditing=false;
})
```

You can use an on click event to perform a function for when a user clicks on the map, a popup will show up but only when the user isn't currently drawing:

```
function onMapClick(e) {
 if (currentlyEditing == false){
    var popup = L.popup()
     .setLatLng(e.latlng) 
     .setContent('Popup')
     .openOn(map);
 } else {
     return
 }
};
map.on('click', onMapClick);
leafletFeatureLayer.bindPopup(popup);
```

Except we only want the popup to show if where the mouse click occurs intersects with the polygon (This is kind of hacked together, there may be a better way):

```
var marker;
//query layer
var query = L.esri.query({
  url: "https://geodata.wgnhs.uwex.edu/arcgis/rest/services/lslc/MapServer/0", 
});
var popup;
//on map click check if editing before adding a popup
function onMapClick(e) { 
  console.log("hi");
   marker= L.marker(e.latlng);
  if (currentlyEditing === false){
    console.log("not editing");
    //does the position clicked intersect with the polygon?
    query.intersects(marker);
     query.run(function(error,ids, featureCollection, response){
      console.log('Found ' + featureCollection.features.length + ' features');
       //get the id of the polygon that intersects
       query.ids(function(error, ids, response){
        console.log(ids.join(', ') + 'match the provided parameters');
         //show the popup
         popup =L.popup()
           .setLatLng(e.latlng) 
           .setContent('Popup')
           .openOn(map);
       });
     })
   
 } else {
     return;
 }
};  

map.on('click', onMapClick);
```

This should get you 3/4 there to customizing your popups based on their id.

Comment: Note that this answer uses esri to detect intersections..
There's a vanilla js intersection algorithm here:
https://pastebin.com/qSvm69he